# (Machine Learning) Higher polynomial degree + Data balancing = disaster?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, weka, logistic-regression

Data Set: https://www.kaggle.com/c/GiveMeSomeCredit/data (cs-training.csv)

Training Tool: Weka

Data Processing Tool: Python (for higher polynomial degree)

Algorithm: Logistic Regression

Question: Balancing data (by down sampling majority class to make 50:50) or introducing higher polynomial degree SEPARATELY does improve F-measure with a little sacrifice on accuracy.

HOWEVER, balancing data and introducing higher polynomial degree TOGETHER severely undermines accuracy.

Looking at the results below, is it general case or is there something wrong with my experiment design?

```
1. Original Imbalanced Data (90,000) + Polynomial degree of (1)
Accuracy: 93%  F-Measure: 0.074  ROC Area: 0.698
y      n  <-- classified as
79   1,927| y (actual)
60  27,934| n (actual)

2. Original Imbalanced Data (90,000) + Polynomial degree of (2)
Accuracy: 93%  F-Measure: 0.329  ROC Area: 0.806
y      n  <-- classified as
480   1,526| y (actual)
431  27,563| n (actual)

3. Balanced Data (11,942) + Polynomial degree of (1)
Accuracy: 67%  F-Measure: 0.207  ROC Area: 0.73
y      n  <-- classified as
1,292     714| y (actual)
9,157  18,837| n (actual)

4. Balanced Data (11,942) + Polynomial degree of (2)
Accuracy: 6%  F-Measure: 0.123  ROC Area: 0.7
y      n  <-- classified as
1,965   41| y (actual)
27,954  40| n (actual)
```

Comment: You are overfitting.

Comment: What kind of imbalance are we talking about, and what model are you using exactly? I don't want to log in to anything to get the data. Also, it's not clear what your table represents.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut You mean overfitting occurred in number 4 situation? Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @IVlad 1. imbalanced data: 93% didn't default, 7% default 2. I've used Logistic Regression as mentioned above. 3. The table shows True Positive, False Positive, False Negative, and True Negative.